# Getting all array elements with same index in multidimensional array

Tags: php, oop, multidimensional-array

A basic question please. Can somebody help me with getting ALL three maincategory strings (Things to Do, Transportation, and Living). I only found out how to get them individually

```
$categories[0]->maincategory;
```

but how can I get all three of them? Best thanks!

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [maincategory] => Things to Do
        [category] => Activities and  Attractions
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 6
        [maincategory] => Transportation
        [category] => Airport Transfers
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 11
        [maincategory] => Living
        [category] => Broadband Internet
    )
)
```

Comment: So should we get your initial data structure? And desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
foreach ($stdClass as $sclass){
    if(!is_array($sclass)){
     echo $sclass.' ';
     }else{
    foreach ($sclass as $scl){


    echo $scl.' ';
    }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `foreach` loop will do the trick.

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  echo $category->maincategory;
}
```